# qgis2threejs 2d instead of 3d view

Tags: qgis, 3d, qgis2threejs, collada

I want only display a simple cube within qgis2threejs as a collada dae file.
I have this cube created with blender.
But the result of the cubes within qgis2threejs are only in 2D.
The file is OK, I can see the correct 3D cube with blender and in https://threejs.org/editor/
Here an screenshot of my adjustment with preview. After export to web I get the same result, only 2d of the cubes within a point layer.
What should I do, to see the cubes in 3D view?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself:
In this test project I have changed the value for "vertical exaggeration" for the scene settings of qgis2threejs. I have used a very small value (0.00000003) to display my europe map layer correctly. But with this very small value it is not possible to see the 3D of the collada files. If I changed the value for "vertical exaggeration" to "1" I can see now the whole 3D collada files. Maybe it is not reasonable to combine this layers.